# How can I add an element at the end of the array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code that creates an array of binary representation for all the numbers from 0 to 512 and I want to add a random value ad the end of every array. The random value can be 0 or 1. This is the code that generate the array:

```
import numpy as np
POP_SIZE = 50
def initialize_population():
    pixels = 9
    population = []
    for i in range(POP_SIZE):
        chromosome = np.array([list((np.binary_repr(x, pixels))) for x in range(2 ** pixels)], dtype=int)
        population.append(chromosome)
    return population
```

I know that I could use   `np.append(chromosome, np.random.randint(2))` but I do not know how to integrate with the previos code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [random.randint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint):

```
import numpy as np
import random

POP_SIZE = 50
def initialize_population():
    pixels = 9
    population = []
    for i in range(POP_SIZE):
        chromosome = np.array([list(np.binary_repr(x, pixels)) + [random.randint(0, 1)] for x in range(2 ** pixels)], dtype=int)
        population.append(chromosome)
    return population
```

```
print(initialize_population()[0].shape)
(512, 10)
```